# How to retrieve the data using datefield using django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I need to retrieve the data from database using Django Date-field. Tried retrieving the data using Datefield. I'm using Django 2.0, Bootstrap 4, PostgreSQL.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms

class StatusReportForm(forms.Form):
    created_date=forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                            {
                                'class':'datepicker'
                            })) 

#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Statusreport
from .forms import StatusReportForm

def statusreport(request):
   form = StatusReportForm()
     context = {
         form: form
         }
  return render(request, "statusreport.html", context)

class StatusReportDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Statusreport
    template_name = 'statusreport-detail.html'
    def get_object(self):
        instance = get_object_or_404(Statusreport, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
     return instance
 #models.py
 class Statusreport(models.Model):

      created_date= models.DateField()
      taskname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
      def __str__(self):
          return self.taskname

      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('statusreport:statusreport-detail', kwargs={'slug': 
          self.slug})

 def pre_save_statusreport_receiver(instance, *args, **kwargs):
     if not instance.slug:
       instance.slug = instance.created_date
 pre_save.connect(pre_save_statusreport_receiver, sender= Statusreport)

 #statusreport.html

 <main class="container">
   <form>
       <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px">
           <div class="col">
              <label class = 'control-label' for="date">Select Date: </label>
              <input data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">
            </br>
        </br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-md active" role="button" 
             aria-pressed="true">Get Reports</a>
          </div>
       </div>
     </form>
  </main>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      weekStart: 1,
      daysOfWeekHighlighted: "6,0",
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  </script>
```

Note: I need it to work like on-clicking "Get reports" button from there it needs to move to http://localhost:8000/statusreport/{{created_date}}/

But I couldn't able to get the reports.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form method=POST action={% url 'get_posts_from'%}>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="row" style="padding-top: 100px">
           <div class="col">
              <label class = 'control-label' for="date">Select Date: </label>
              <input name='date-needed' data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" id="datepicker">
            </br>
        </br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-md active" role="button" 
             aria-pressed="true">Get Reports</a>
          </div>
       </div>
     </form>
```

First you must make your form method to post

then you add the `action` which is your url to the view that will manage the posted data

then add the `csrf_token` to the form

then you must give `name` to the `#datepicker` so when you go to your view

you get the `request.POST["date"]` which is your date that has been choosen in the form

in the `urls.py`

```
url(r'^(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.get_posts_from, name='get_posts_from')
```

then in views

```
def get_posts_from(request, date):
    if request.method =="POST":
         date = request.POST['date']
    #here you put your logic the date can be either picked from
    #the post or even trough the URL on his own 
    return HttpResponse("POSTS from",date)
```

Comment: Thanks @kostadin. But `get_posts_from` can we written with in `class StatusReportDetailView` so that I can retrieve the data from models.

Answer (score 0):

replace  this line

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Statusreport, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

with this

`instance = get_object_or_404(Statusreport, created_date=self.kwargs['slug'])`

and pass `created_date` as the argument in as slug

Comment: Hi @Pankaj I've slug modelfield, that will be the same as created_date. So, this won't works.  And more over after clicking the "Get Reports" only it moves to the Detail view. First i need to access the "Get Reports" ~> `class StatusReportDetailView`

Comment: if you want to get list of reports for the data you should  use ListView and then use `StatusReportDetailView` from there 
please post the error or log you get while clicking on `Get Reports`